# print out if the two inputs are anagrams of each other or not

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare, anagram

My program takes two inputs from the user and finds out if they are anagrams of each other so far i got the inputs and got them sorted in alphabetical order but not sure how to compare them to print out  if they are the same or not heres my code obviously the string==strings is incorrect

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_string(char*);

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    char strings[100];

printf("\nThis program will ask you for 2 words and compare them to see if they are anagrams of each other\n\n");


printf("Enter first word\n");
gets(string);

sort_string(string);

/*commented out for testing of function*/
/*printf("%s\n", string);*/

printf("Enter  second word for comparison\n");
gets(strings);
sort_string(strings);
/*commented out for testing of function*/
/*printf("%s\n", strings);*/


if (sizeof string==sizeof strings)
    printf("\nThe two words ARE  anagrams of each other.\n");
else
    printf("\nThe two words are NOT anagrams of each other.\n");


printf("\nThank You %d  %d\n\n",sizeof string, sizeoof strings);



   return 0;
}



/*function to sort in alphabetical order to be used for comparison*/ 
void sort_string(char *s)
{
   int c, d = 0, length;
   char *pointer, *result, ch;

   length = strlen(s);

   result = (char*)malloc(length+1);

   pointer = s;

   for ( ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++ )
   {
      for ( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
      {
         if ( *pointer == ch )
         {
            *(result+d) = *pointer;
            d++;
         }
         pointer++;
      }
      pointer = s;
   }
   *(result+d) = '\0';

   strcpy(s, result);
   free(result);
}
```

Comment: `string1` and `string2` would be much better names than `string` and `strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Also, you might want to consider using [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) or [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) for `sort_string()`.